# Order of a group element. [$\operatorname{ord}(x)$]

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

$\newcommand{\ord}{\operatorname{ord}}$

***I need to prove the following***

> $(i)$ $\forall x\in G\,:\ord(x)=\ord(x^{-1})$ 
>   $(ii)$ $\forall x,g\in G\,:\ord(gxg^{-1})=\ord(x)\qquad$ (for $\ord(x)<\infty$ and $\ord(x)=\infty$)

**proof $(i)$**: let $\ord(x)=n$ and let $\ord(x^{-1})=m$. 
\begin{align}
\ord(x)=n&\Leftrightarrow x^n=e\tag{1}\\
&\Rightarrow x^n \cdot (x^{-1})^n=(x^{-1})^n\\
&\Rightarrow e=(x^{-1})^n
\end{align}
Therefore $m=\ord(x^{-1})\le \ord(x)=n$

And
\begin{align}
\ord(x^{-1})=m&\Leftrightarrow (x^{-1})^m=e\tag{2}\\
&\Rightarrow (x^{-1})^m \cdot ((x^{-1})^m)^{-1}=x^{m}\\
&\Rightarrow e=x^{m}
\end{align}
Therefore $m=\ord(x^{-1})\ge \ord(x)=n$. So we know that $\ord(x^{-1})=\ord(x)$

---

**proof $(iia)$**: Let $\ord(x)=n$ and let $\ord(gxg^{-1})=m$ and assume that $\ord(x)<\infty$
\begin{align}
\ord(gxg^{-1})=m\Leftrightarrow(gxg^{-1})^m&=e\tag{3}\\
\end{align}
This is the same as
\begin{align}
\prod_{k=1}^{m}{(gxg^{-1})}&=gxg^{-1}\cdots gxg^{-1}\tag{4}\\
&=gx^mg^{-1}\\
&=e
\end{align}
So we know that 
\begin{align}
&gx^mg^{-1}=e\\
&\Rightarrow gx^m=g\\
&\Rightarrow x^m=g^{-1}g\\
&\Rightarrow x^m=e
\end{align}
Therefore $n=\ord(x)\le \ord(gxg^{-1})=m$
We can do the same for
\begin{align}
&x^n=e\tag{5}\\
&\Rightarrow gx^m=g\\
&\Rightarrow gx^mg^{-1}=e
\end{align}
Therefore $n=\ord(x)\ge \ord(gxg^{-1})=m\Longrightarrow n=m$

**proof $(iib)$**: And here I get stuck.

---

**My question:**

> How can i prove $\ord(gxg^{-1})=\ord(x)\qquad$ if $\ord(x)=\infty$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose $\operatorname{ord}(x)= \infty$.

Then $\forall n \in \mathbb N: x^n \neq e$, and $gxg^{-1}= gx^ng^{-1}$. Suppose $\operatorname{ord}(gxg^{-1}) = n$. Then $gx^ng^{-1} = e$, therefore $x^n = e$. So $\operatorname{ord}(gxg^{-1})$ has to be $\infty$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Show that $(gxg^{-1})^m = gx^mg^{-1}$ (you can use induction). Now assume for contradiction $gxg^{-1}$ has finite order. Then $gx^mg^{-1} = e$ for some $m \in \mathbb{N}$. Then what is $x^m$?

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $x$ has infinite order, and for contradiction suppose $gxg^{-1}$ has finite order $n$. Then $(gxg^{-1})^n = gx^ng^{-1} = 1$ hence $x^n = 1$, a contradiction.